# Oracle Connection string Issues?

Tags: oracle11g, odbc, connection-string

I have an application which is using oracle database and i want to use odbc to connect with the application .

i used odbc to connect mssql server with the  following connection string format    and it was fine

**Data Source=myServerAddress;Integrated Security=SSPI;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;**

how to connect oracle database  , i tried

**Data Source=myServerAddress;Integrated Security=,yes;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Username=username;password=password**

But no luck , wats the correct connection stting for oracle ?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: @Alex.K  wat to use in datasource , is it sid or odbc nane which i made

Comment: @AlexK. ...  .. . .. . .. ..